# How to enable reading PDF annotations in zathura

Tags: pdf, zathura

I'm using Zathura document viewer and I wanted to have some support for PDF annotations, I'm using the `ZATHURA-PDF-MUPDF` and as far as I know mypdf has support for PDF annotations, but yet Zathura doesn't.

I need some way to enable that in zathura, is there some plugin that I can use to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

SADLY, IT'S NOT SUPPORTED AND I WISH TO SAY YET, BUUUT, CHECK [THIS](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/hcy5p7/bspwm_taking_notes_in_zathura/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) OUT.
ALTHOUGH IF U USE ARCH, U CAN USE [LLPP](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/llpp) .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/456395)